# Reference object array outside of function it is declared in

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    Tile map[50][50];

    ///// Generate Map \\\\\

    buildRoom(10, 10, 10, 10, 1);

    return 0;
}

void buildRoom(int startX, int startY, int sizeX, int sizeY, int direction)
{
    if (direction == 1)
    {
        for (int x; x++; x > sizeX)
            map[startX + x][startY].type = 1;
    }
}
```

Currently the map variable doesn't exist in the context of the buildRoom() function. 
How would I be able to access the map variable outside of the main() function?

Comment: You should read up on [passing objects by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).

Comment: Pass it by-reference or make it global. The choice is yours.

Comment: You should take a look at that for loop, it doesn't look right

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a parameter. (Arrays, unlike other parameters, are not copied when passed by value. Modifying the parameter will alter the external array).

```
int main()
{
    Tile map[50][50];

    ///// Generate Map \\\\\
    buildRoom(map, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1);
}

void buildRoom(Tile map[50][50], int startX, int startY, int sizeX, int sizeY, int direction)
{
    if (direction == 1)
    {
        for (int x; x++; x > sizeX)
             map[startX + x][startY].type = 1;
    }
}
```

Or put it in a class.

```
#include <cassert>

class Map
{
public:
    static const int MapSizeX = 50;
    static const int MapSizeY = 50;

    void buildRoom(int startX, int startY, int sizeX, int sizeY, int direction)
    {
        if (direction == 1)
        {
            for (int x; x++; x > sizeX)
                 GetTile(startX + x, startY).type = 1;
        }
    }

    const Tile& GetTile(int x, int y) const
    {
        assert(x > 0 && x < MapSizeX && y > 0 && y < MapSizeY);
        return data[x][y];
    }

    Tile& GetTile(int x, int y)
    {
        assert(x > 0 && x < MapSizeX && y > 0 && y < MapSizeY);
        return data[x][y];
    }

private:
    Tile data[MapSizeX][MapSizeY];
}

int main()
{
    Map mymap;

    ///// Generate Map \\\\\
    mymap.buildRoom(10, 10, 10, 10, 1);
}
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks for the lightning fast response!

Comment: @user2744960 I made a slight modification.